# how to get Spinner List's selected items's text and fill EditText in android with that value

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-spinner, android, android-event

when I try to get the EditText object in the Itemselected function of selection listener the line throws NullPointerException

```
<resources>
<string-array name="gender">
    <item name="Male">Male</item>
    <item name="Female">Female</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

**layout**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="answer" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:entries="@array/gender"
    android:prompt="@string/spin_prompt" />
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    Spinner sp= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

**Spinner Activity**

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {

                String selec = (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)).toString();

                EditText ans= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer); 
                //NullPointerException at the time of retrieving EditText object 

                ans.setText(selec);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }

}
```

**Log-Cat Error Entries**

```
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at com.practice.menu.SpinnerActivity.onItemSelected(SpinnerActivity.java:19)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-21 17:23:42.232: E/AndroidRuntime(4019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: a full NPE stacktrace would help

Comment: @donfuxx i am new to android and eclipse so do you mean error shown in Log-Cat from NPE stacktrace

Comment: what is in the onCreate method of SpinnerActivity?

Comment: yes, the errors shown in logcat @UDB

Comment: @donfuxx i have added the NPE stacktrace

Comment: @donfuxx and what is that?

Comment: see my proposal of how to implement the listener in my answer @UDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
```

You are trying to instantiate another activity and you try to set it as the listener. That won't work because Android Activities don't like it to get instantiated explicitly.

Try implementing listener for your spinner like this:

```
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

the SpinnerActivity you should not need then anymore

Answer (score 0):

this one also work in simple way.Make sure OnonItemSelected variable should define like i,l.

> `String spinnerText3=Spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();

Spinner3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> sdocode, View view,int i, long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
        editText.requestFocus();

    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(
            AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }});`
```